# How I can determine that banner is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-tag-manager

I have a banner with code below

```
<!-- Start GPT Async Tag -->
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var gptadslots = [];
  var googletag = googletag || {cmd:[]};
</script>
<script>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    //Adslot 2 declaration
    gptadslots.push(googletag.defineSlot('/268518576/Mydomain/Mydomain_mobile_300x600', [[300,600]], 'div-gpt-ad-3957884-2')
                             .addService(googletag.pubads()));

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();

    googletag.pubads().set('page_url', 'https://m.mydomain.com/');

    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
<!-- End GPT Async Tag -->

<!-- Async AdSlot 2 for Ad unit 'Mydomain/Mydomain_mobile_300x600' ### Size: [[300,600]] -->
<!-- Adslot's refresh function: googletag.pubads().refresh([gptadslots[1]]) -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-3957884-2'>
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-3957884-2'); });
  </script>
</div>
<!-- End AdSlot 2 -->
```

Show banner or not, depends on the targeting policy.
In the HTML banner is an iframe. But i can't get this iframe by id, such like this

```
$('#5r3rr').contents().find('body').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

1- **Note:** Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain  [same-origin policy.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

2- Make sure that your script loads after the target iframe , for this i suggest to do something like this (i assumed that the given ID is correct):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ $('#5r3rr').contents().find('body').html(); }, 1000);
 });
```

3- to check if the id exist or not (or the iframe was loaded or not) you can do this:

```
if($("#5r3rr").length == 0) {
  //it doesn't exist
}
```